# Why does setting freemarkers' default encoding break reading template (everything is in utf-8)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, freemarker

I have a spring boot project with gradle kts, and I am using the standalone freemarker library `implementation("org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.32")` for templating texts for frontend.

I put together the following code:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_32);
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new ClassPathResource("templates").getFile());
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
cfg.setOutputEncoding("utf-8");

Template template = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
System.out.println("template=" + template);

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("vehicles", List.of(new Vehicle("auto", 60), new Vehicle("koloběžka", 5)));

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
template.process(data, stringWriter);
String result = stringWriter.toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

Template file `template.ftl` contains (for testing purpuses):

```
jůůů
```

Both the data I am passing to the template ("koloběžka") and the template itself ("jůůů") contain czech characters.

**Problem**
The template file's encoding is `utf-8` (at least that's what I see in intellj).
If I don't set default encoding on the `Configuration` object, it uses the one from my locale (I guess), and that's "`windows-1250`". Then the template is printed (the line with `template=`) correctly (diacritics). 
But if I set the default encoding explicitly to `utf-8`, the line prints `j���`.

**Question**
How is that possible?
I would assume that if both the template and the `Configuration` use `utf-8`, then diacritics should be red correctly.
And the other way bothers me as well - how is it possible that the encoding `windows-1250` the `Configuration` object uses by default is able to read diacritics from the `utf-8` encoded file well?

Comment: *`System.out.println(result);`* is your console set up for UTF-8? If not, it will print garbage

Comment: it's not and I can't find any simple way how to set it. Is there any JVM setting for that?

Comment: you are right! I tried storing the resulting string into an utf-8 encoded file with FileWriter  and it worked fine. So, the problem was indeed printing the string with system.out. If you post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the console you are using is not set up to print out utf-8 properly. You should be able to do this in PowerShell but at the moment I am finding it difficult to find out the way to do this.

Update: the following worked for me, using PowerShell for my Java console:
`$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding`
Executed code:
`System.out.println(new Vehicle("koloběžka", 5));`
Output:

```
PS C:\Users\goose> java Vehicle
name=koloběžka,id=5
PS C:\Users\goose>
```